# Tree decomposition by hand for understanding

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, trees

I am implementing "algorithm 2" from the paper "Treewidth computations I. Upper bounds" by Bodlander and Koster[1,page5] and I am not sure if I understand it or not.

As I understand, the algoritm will always return a tree decomposion that looks like a linked list.

If there are n nodes in the tree, then the tree will have n-1 edges. Is that correct?

I tried the algorithm by hand:
http://oi59.tinypic.com/nz4y1d.jpg

I have three lines in each column. The first column is the input graph, the second is the graph after I have eliminated v1, and the last line in red are the tree decomposition. I start from the left and I go to the right column for each recursive call.

Have I understood it correctly

[1] http://www.math2.rwth-aachen.de/~koster/paper/boko08b_rv.pdf

Edit: I think I have problem to understand the return statement when n =/= 1

Comment: _Bodlaender_ (oops missed edit). see also [tree decomposition fastest algorithm in practice](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41651/tree-decomposition-fastest-algorithm-in-practise) / [cs.se] where the answer might indicate that the algorithm(s) have never actually been implemented (?)

Comment: vnz, this is another paper by Bonlaender!

Comment: seems to be returning a _bag_ but having trouble following $X_{V_1}$ vs $X_V$, do you get it? fyi all [chat room on this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23138/room-for-niclas-jonsson-and-vzn)